# Python dictionary issues

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi i am struggling to append two values to a dictionary, see the code below but i want to append the average score to their names.

```
 Question = raw_input("""How would you like to view the class?
 A) By Average, highest to lowest:
B) By Highest score, highest to lowest:
C) By Alphaetical order:
""")
Question = Question.title()
if Question == "A" :
    for key, value in Classdict.items():
        Avg = sum(map(int, value))/ float(len(value))
        global AvgDict
        AvgDict = {}
        for key in Classdict:
            if key in AvgDict:
                AvgDict[key].append(Avg)
            else:
                AvgDict[key] = Avg
        print AvgDict
    Classopen.close()
    Questiontwo = raw_input("""How would yuu like to view it?
A)By highest score, highest to lowest:
B)By Alphaetical order: 
""")

    Questiontwo = Questiontwo.title()
    if Questiontwo == "A":
        print "You selected highest score, highest to lowest"
        sortedavghigh = sorted(AvgDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        print sortedavghigh[::-1]
    elif Questiontwo == "B":
        print "You selected to sort it alphabetically"
        sortedavgapha = sorted(AvgDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        print sortedavgalpha
```

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to store/do you have stored in your `Classdict`?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, this line is wrong:

```
AvgDict[key] = Avg
```

I think it should instead be:

```
AvgDict[key] = [Avg]
```

so that you have a list that you can append to.

The appending code could also be written like this, which I feel looks a bit clearer:

```
if key not in AvgDict:
    AvgDict[key] = []
AvgDict[key].append(Avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a value to `AvgDict`, make sure you put it as a list, otherwise, when you use `.append(Avg)`, it does not work.
One may implenet it like this:

```
AvgDict[key] = [Avg]
```